# Strange behavior in Extension Library Name Picker

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

In IE, Firefox, and Chrome, when I use the Extension Library name picker, not all names are shown.  The data provider is set to dominoNABNamePicker.  This is 853 up 1.  On the server.

If the NAB has 250 entries, the last shown name (using the scroll bar) starts with a J.  The rest of the names are only visible by entering criteria in the search bar, for example: "M".  Is there any way to be able to see all of the entries just by scrolling?

Bonus strange behavior, in IE if the list is still displaying the default names (no criteria has been entered) and you click on the bottom of the scroll bar, expecting that the lower values would be displayed, it "jumps" and resets to the top of the list (doesn't actually go anywhere).

This is all on a plain vanilla page with nothing else on the XPage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the maxRowCount Dojo attribute that Sean Cull mentions here http://www.seancull.co.uk/public/seancull.nsf/dx/getting-the-xpage-extension-library-name-pickers-to-show-more-than-50-names.htm

I too hit a problem with the finite number of entries, but didn't come across Sean's link until just now. http://www.intec.co.uk/extension-library-value-picker-and-extlib-dijit-pickerlistsearch/

Comment: Huzzah!  For the record, I DID Google the issue and didn't get his blog post in the results.  This worked!  Thanks muchly.

Comment: I tried "Extension Library Picker Limit" in Google. That's where I also found my article (which I'd forgotten I'd written!). I'll make a note of it for version 2 of the book.

Comment: Any thoughts on the whacky IE behavior?  (Other than "don't use IE"? :-) )

Comment: Don't know, but it sounds like it's doing a "reload". Is there any client-server activity on IE developer tools?